# react native map How to render marker that only in the screen view?

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps, react-native-map-clustering

I am using react native map, and I have more than 10000 marker I want to render those that inside the screen view,
How to achieve that?

Comment: Please add minimal relevant code as `MapView` and `Marker` components implementation and `marker` data